# Website nav links not working on IE9

Tags: css, button, internet-explorer-9, nav

My website: http://botvps.com

The text on the button is not appearing.
I have already made an IE css for IE 8 or lower.

What do I need to do?

Regards,
LB

Comment: Welcome to SO. Posting a link is not a problem in itself, but please also show some relevant HTML here so the question can have value to future generations.

Comment: Just as Pekka writes, add more information and proper code sections in your question. Your site will change and then the question here will expire. Also, what button do you mean?

Comment: This looks like it is a problem with your Cufon maybe?

Comment: Even better would be a jsfiddle so you can include HTML and CSS in an easy-to-build working example: http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Cufon 1.09, an outdated version. Please use the new 1.09i version of Cufon, which adds support for Internet Explorer 9.

I tested your site with 1.09i, it renders fine then!

1. Download cufon-yui.js from the following website:
   http://cufon.shoqolate.com/
2. Replace the following file on the server with the new javascript:
   http://www.botvps.com/js/cufon-yui.js

Comment: So my users need to download this? Please explain

Comment: The current cufon core script is in the head of your website: <script src="js/cufon-yui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>. You have to replace the cufon-yui.js file on the server with the newer version on the link I posted.

Comment: Just back from bike ride, I'll try this out now!

Answer (score 1):

you can use this meta tag line and put it inside the `<head>` tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

this will make ie9 work in compatibility mode to ie8 and will solve the problem if you don't

have problems in ie8 stylesheet

Comment: Tried this but the end user still had errors.After going into that mode, did it not use the IE css?

Comment: i didn't understand what you mean

Answer (score 0):

```
 <!--[if IE 5]>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie5.css" />
 <![endif]-->
 <!--[if IE 6]>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6.css" />
 <![endif]-->
 <!--[if IE 7]>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie.css" />
 <![endif]-->
 <!--[if IE 8]>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8.css" />
 <![endif]-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="layout.css" />
```

Comment: put this between your <head></head> code :) with the proper .css files.

Comment: This really isn't an answer to the question - the OP is asking specifically about text on a button.

Comment: Do I do the same for IE9?

<!--[if IE 9]>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie9.css" />

Comment: That's a start, then I need to add to my .css, help would be useful :)

Comment: Surely there is a more zen way than spamming all browsers with a giant list of if statements...